# Need help for user validation steps SWIFT + TWILIO + NODEJS + COUCHBASE

Tags: node.js, swift, couchbase

So i'm learning Swift and i'm trying to validate user inputs on IOS app for a class project but i'm not sure if i'm following the right steps. Can you give me some feedbacks ?
Here's how it goes:

- User enters phone number, check if it's valid.
  Send twilio code notification if user phone number doesn't exist in db to set phoneVerified = true
- User proceed to next screen to enter email & password
  then send link to set user.status = true

  Datas are sent in JSON format to Couchbase via NodeJs route.

I'm not sure if datas should be validated on client-side or server-side or both. I've been told never trust user input but i was working on websites at the time. I'm really confused, Does it apply for phone apps also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll say you have two choices so far:

1 - create the random verification code (usually 6 digits) from the client (meaning the user's phone), then send it to your api along the user's phone number so that twillio can send the code within the twillio's message body.

2 - create the random verification code from your api and repeat the end steps of **option 1**

> Client Side (let's use option 1, and think of the following as psuedo-code)

- verify the input phone number, and if not valid, tell the user to do fix it.
- create the random code and save it to `UserDefault`. (we save it because if something happen while your app is being used, of course you'll also add a logic for **request another code**)
- create the request body dictionary that contains the code and phone number i.e `[phone: 182822939, code: 83920]`
- using either **URLSession** or **Alamofire** you do a `POST` request to your nodejs api along the body that you've created from the previous step.

> NodeJS API

- here, you get the phone number from your request object like `const phoneNumber = req.body.phonenumber`, and the code like `const code = req.body.code`.
- you create the twillio sending object using the phone, and you add the code within the message body and you send it.
- if the message was successfully sent, return **200 Ok** from the response, else you return the error with a **404 code**

> Client Side Again

As of now, the user gets the code, now with need to check if the input code and the code from UserDefault are identical. if valid you continue with your login process, otherwise you notify the user with an alert (so that's why is important to also add the **request another code** in case the user never receive the code.)

Voila, also this is not the only way to approach your problem.

Comment: Wow ! thx for the explanation, It is clearer for me now. There are many ways indeed, i'm gonna try your approach. Have a wonderful day sir :)

Comment: welcome and don't forget to vote if helpful

Answer (score 0):

Server side should always have the validation. You can't trust user input. Your phone app also will use some APIs to communicate with the server right? What if I don't use your app and just send request to those APIs?

Also, your design looks like it has some flaws.

What if a user verifies a phone but exits the app (user phone is verified in the database right?). But another user requests your API for email and password?

Do you have anything in place that, the person who verified the phone is registering with the email and password?

Please specify more details.

Comment: Thx you for your feedback.
To be more specific, I'm taking Uber as an example, at launching screen, User needs to enter his phone number, the number is sent to server for validation process (regex, number exist in db ?) then a generated code is sent to user, if user types the right code, phoneVerified = true and then he can proceed to next step which is entering email and password, make validation process, send verification link through Nodemailer to user email. If link is clicked then userStatus = true, if phoneVerified == userStatus, user have access to app functionalities. That's it